# Detecting, whether user enter a string value or number in to a input field

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an input field and one button. When the user clicks the button, first I check whether they entered a number or not.  If it is a non-numeric string then nothing should happen. If it's a number then I will do some modification to the above gray div. When I enter a number and log its type to the console, it shows that the data type of the value is "string." So how do I check for the correct data type?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='test'></div>
  <p><input type='text' id='myText'/>
  <input type='button' value='click' id='myButton'/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var el = document.getElementById('myButton'),
    elOne = document.getElementById('myText'),
    container = document.getElementById('test');

el.onclick = function(){
  var data = elOne.value;

  if(typeof data === 'number'){
    console.log('number');
  }else if(typeof data === 'string') {



     console.log('string');
  }
};
```

And here is the jsbin link - http://jsbin.com/hequr/1/

Comment: `.value` **always** returns a string.

Comment: ok, but how to convert back to number, if user enter a number.

Comment: @FelixKling, when `type="text"`

Comment: `->` [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770/218196)

Comment: Even with the input type `number`, `.value` will return a string. Just the user presentation of the `input` changes.

Comment: ok friends i got this snippet is working fine.                  function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

Comment: You can use regular expression check for this.

Comment: ok, we could do that as-well. can you send the link.

Answer (score 0):

use functions like `isNaN()` or `isNumeric()` or use Regular expression `\[0-9].*\`